# Any way to mute/unmute sound when playing a StageVideo video?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, audio

I'm having a hard time trying to control the sound when I reproduce a StageVideo video, it's always on, no matter if I do this: SoundMixer.audioPlaybackMode = AudioPlaybackMode.AMBIENT;

Is there any way to achieve a switch sound button functionality?, preferable if it doesn't involve an ANE.

Comment: If you're using a `NetStream`, you can use it's `soundTransform` property.

Comment: No it doesn't work on iOS sadly, I've tried it.